# how to add class after random number is selected in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, random, react-component

I have an array from 1 to 50 and I am displaying them. Besides, I have a button which is selecting random numbers from 1 to 50 again. So what I am trying to do is, I want to add 'active' class to the div when the randomly selected number is equal to it. So here is my component:

```
import React from "react";    import { useState } from "react";

const Board = () => {
    let className="bingo-ball__container";
    const [randomNumber, setRandomNumber] = useState(0);
    const numbers = [
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21,
        22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
        41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
    ];
    const [selectedNumbers, setSelectedNumbers] = useState([]);
    const numberSelect = () => {
        setRandomNumber(Math.floor(Math.random() * 50));
        setSelectedNumbers(selectedNumbers => [...selectedNumbers, randomNumber]);
        for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if(randomNumber == i) {
                className += ' active';
            }
        } 
    };
    return (
        <div className="game-board">
            <div id="selected-number">
                <div className="selected">
                    <div className="bingo-ball__container">
                        <div className="bingo-ball bingo-ball">
                            <h1 className="bingo-ball__text">{randomNumber}</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button
                    className="button button3"
                    onClick={numberSelect}
                >
                    Select Number
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="bingo-grid">
                {numbers.map((number, index) => (
                        <div className="bingo-grid__row">
                            <div className={className} key={index}>
                                <div className="bingo-ball bingo-ball">
                                    <h3 className="bingo-ball__text">{number}</h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Board;
```

So className={className} should be changed if the random number is equal to the number in mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
 <div className={className} key={index}>
```

Compare the number with random number in the numbers mapping function.

```
<div className={'bingo-ball__container' + (number === randomNumber ? ' active':'')} key={index}>
```

Since the below loop iterates over all numbers, it will eventually append `'active'` to `className` at the end of the loop.

```
       for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if(randomNumber == i) {
                className += ' active';
            }
        }
```

**Edit:**
If u need to keep the selected ones highlighted u can use a map to keep track of the selected numbers.

```
    let className="bingo-ball__container";
    const [randomNumber, setRandomNumber] = useState(0);
    const [isSelected, setIsSelected ] = useState({});// new map to keep track
    const numbers = [
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21,
        22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
        41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
    ];
    const [selectedNumbers, setSelectedNumbers] = useState([]);
    const numberSelect = () => {
        const newRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50;
        setRandomNumber(newRandom);
        setSelectedNumbers(selectedNumbers => [...selectedNumbers, randomNumber]);
        setIsSelected({...isSelected, [newRandom]:true} // update as selected
    };
```

And in the rendering function refer to the object,

```
<div className={'bingo-ball__container' + (isSelected[randomNumber] ? ' active':'')} key={index}>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also thought about it but the thing is every time when I click the button the active class is changing. But I want selectedNumbers have active class all the time

Comment: what is isRandom, can you check your answer?

Comment: My bad. Edited it. please check now

Comment: Thanks again but this time all of them being active :(